# Contact Form 7, After Mail Send Form Hide and Another Div Show

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to hide the form after sending the mail in contact form 7. And I want to do another div show with success message in place of the form. Like the screenshot below.

Forms can be hidden with CSS after mail is sent. But I can't do another div show with success message.

[image]

```
.wpcf7-form.sent { display:none; }
```

Comment: You could add in the contact form 7 form wysiwyg a div with the thank you message and all you want, put it as `display: none`, after the form is sent display it

Answer (score 1):

you can use the DOM call back `wpcf7mailsent` in JavaScript to hide the form and show another div.

Basic example

```
var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );
 
wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
  jQuery(this).hide();
  // Some code here to show your custom message element
}, false );
```

[Source](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/)

try this code and let me know

```
var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );
 
wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
  $this = jQuery(this);
  $this.children('.ltr_form_area').hide();
  $this.children('.ltr_form_success_div').show();
}, false );
```

Comment: I tried for a long time. But it did not work. I want do hide this div class ".ltr_form_area" , and show this div class ".ltr_form_success_div"  after mail sennding.... any idea please ?

Comment: I added a code that should work, please let me know if it worked